# Sed: Add quotes around entire second capture group

Tags: regex, bash, sed

```
#!/bin/bash

TEST="--extra-vars user=jsmith a=abcd --test"
echo $TEST | sed -re "s/(--extra-vars\s)([a-zA-Z0-9\=\s]*)/\1\"\2\"/g"
```

I am using sed to add literal quotes around the entirety of the second capture group but for some reason its only partially quoting the group. The expected output for this would be `--extra-vars "user=jsmith a=abcd" --test` but instead I am seeing `--extra-vars "user=jsmith" a=abcd --test`. I thought using the global sed modifier would help but it hasnt seemed to fix the issue.

Heres a link to the [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mK9hB3/3)

Comment: Unrelated but remember to quotes your variable expansion or they will undergo word splitting, also consider to use single quotes in sed expressions: `echo "$TEST" | sed -re '...'`

Comment: s/consider to/always/

Comment: You should consider posting your script to the code review stackexchange so they can suggest a better approach all together. This is not a situation a well written program will find itself in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you will need to use `[:space:]` in character classes:

```
TEST="--extra-vars user=jsmith a=abcd --test"
echo "$TEST" | sed -re 's/(--extra-vars\s)([a-zA-Z0-9\=[:space:]]*)/\1"\2"/g'
#                                                       ^
#                                                       Use [:space:]
```

This will however also include the last space after `abcd`:

```
--extra-vars "user=jsmith a=abcd "--test
```

A way to prevent that is to add `(\s-)*` to the end of the search and `\3` to the replacement:

```
TEST="--extra-vars user=jsmith a=abcd --test"
echo "$TEST" | sed -re 's/(--extra-vars\s)([a-zA-Z0-9\=[:space:]]*)(\s-)*/\1"\2"\3/g'
```

Which gives:

```
--extra-vars "user=jsmith a=abcd" --test
```

You can also consider using something like Perl which have PCRE:

```
echo "$TEST" | perl -pe 's/(?<=--extra-vars\s).*?(?=\s-|$)/"$&"/'
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the output you posted from the input you posted is just:

```
TEST="--extra-vars user=jsmith a=abcd --test"
$ echo "$TEST" | sed 's/ \(.*\) / "\1" /'
--extra-vars "user=jsmith a=abcd" --test
```

If that's not adequate then edit your question to show some more truly representative sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if you use `[:space:]` or an **actual** space character (i.e. `([a-zA-Z0-9\= ]*)` for your second group, it will do what you want, except it'll match that space after `abcd`:

```
--extra-vars "user=jsmith a=abcd "--test
```

So use one of the two, but you'll have to adjust your regex to do what you want.  It's difficult for us to give you a regular expression because we aren't sure what kind of string you're expecting, but this might be able to work:

```
echo "$TEST" | sed -re "s!(--extra-vars\s)([a-zA-Z0-9\=]*\s)([a-zA-Z0-9\=]*)!\1\"\2\3\"!g"
```

Comment: The expected output is stated above.

Comment: @Zee, not expected output, but expected string (or input, rather).  Basically saying, we're not sure what else $TEST can be, or what else you may expect $TEST to be.  I'm sure there are other options for $TEST, but if there isn't then we can easily give you a very literal regex to solve this **specific** string.

For example, this would solve your problem:
`echo "$TEST" | sed -re "s/(--extra-vars\s)([a-zA-Z0-9\= ]*d)/\1\"\2\"/g"`, but that's only if you expect your second group to always end with a `d` which I doubt.